# Find 2D transformation to merge/stich 2 datasets (tuple) with overlap in python with sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Lets say I have 2 datasets / tuples "Left" and "Right". Some values are present in both datasets due to the overlap. How can I find the best transfromation for "Right" to combine it with "Left"?
I just found geometric transformation for matrices and images but not for datasets.

In this example, the data is identical besides the transformation. What if the data differs slighlty with noise? Would the best transformation be the result of a RANSAC Fit, i.e. a homography. This should be possible with Sklearn (Scikit-learn), isn't it? Again, most of the results what I looked were based on matrices and images and not datasets.

I have the feeling this problem occurred many times and a nice solution is definitely somewhere out there but unfortunately I couldn't find any.

Thank you very much for your help!

[image: example datasets]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Load data from txt file
dataleft = np.genfromtxt(r'C:\Data2MergeLeft.txt',delimiter="\t")
dataright = np.genfromtxt(r'C:\Data2MergeRight.txt',delimiter="\t")

#Find overlap
overlapleft = np.where(dataleft[:,0]>=dataright[1,0])[0]
overlapright = np.where(dataright[:,0]<dataleft[-1,0])[0]

#Trim data (overlap only)
olleft = dataleft[overlapleft]
olright = dataright[overlapright]

#Transformed data ->newarray
olrightnew = olright

#Initial values of transformation
offsetx = 10
linyconstant = 5
linyfactor = 1.2

#Loop for optimization
#Transformation
olrightnew[:,0] = olright[:,0]-offsetx
olrightnew[:,1] = (olright[:,1]-linyconstant)/linyfactor

#Residual
residuals = olright[:,1]-olrightnew[:,1]
sqresidual = residuals*residuals
residual = np.sum(sqresidual)
```

Comment: This looks like raman spectra, is shifting in x really desirable?

Comment: It is, but this is just an example. In general only the the intensity is adjusted to combine both spectra. But if the x-axis is not properly calibrated or cannot be calibrated (wich is often the case) this would be a problem.

Comment: please add your attempt to solve the problem (working code example)

Comment: I would interpolate the overlaping region to have common x-coordinates and then minimize the difference between both while allowing one of the datasets to shift and scale.

Comment: I think a common x-axis is not necessary since the x-axis of the data (right) has to be shifted anyway. 
Maybe it is to trivial but how do you set up a optimization routine with two independent fit functions (one for x (constant shift) and one for y (linear))?